# Why go stdout cannot work with shell pipeline?

Tags: shell, go

### Example

```
go |grep help
```

### Expect

go command output filtered.

### Addition

```
[xxx@localhost]$ lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    :core-4.1-amd64:core-4.1-noarch
Distributor ID: Fedora
Description:    Fedora release 33 (Thirty Three)
Release:    33
Codename:   ThirtyThree
[xxx@localhost]$ go version
go version go1.15.6 linux/amd64
```

Comment: Only the actual output / results of a Unix tool belong to stdout. Progress information, diagnostics and logging belong to stderr.

https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Standard-Streams.html

Answer (score 1):

This isn't `stdout`, it's `stderr`. Try redirecting `stdout` to `stderr`:

```sh
$ go 2>&1 | grep help
Use "go help <command>" for more information about a command.
Additional help topics:
Use "go help <topic>" for more information about that topic.
```